# Validation unique using scope

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a table `adm_users` in the `database` with these two rows:

```
| id | username         | club_id |
|----|------------------|---------|
| 1  | daniel@gmail.com | 1       |
| 2  | jhon@gmail.com   | 1       |
```

My logic is, the email is unique only for the same `club_id`, here is the validation code:

```
->add('username', 'unique', [
    'rule' => ['validateUnique',
        ['scope' => 'club_id']
    ],
    'provider' => 'table'
])
```

The issue is, the rule is allowing change `daniel@gmail.com` to `jhon@gmail.com`, they have the same `club_Id` so this is not supposed to happen.

Here's the result of the `SQL Log`:

```
SELECT 1 AS `existing` FROM adm_users AdmUsers WHERE (AdmUsers.username = 'jhon@gmail.com' AND AdmUsers.club_id = NULL AND NOT (AdmUsers.id = 15)) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Isn't the rule method called `validateUnique`, which btw works fine for me?  What does the produced query look like (``SELECT 1 AS `existing` FROM ...``)?

Comment: I changed the `unique` to `validateUnique` and the issue still.. here is the sql log ... `SELECT 1 AS 'existing' FROM adm_users AdmUsers WHERE (AdmUsers.username = 'joao@gmail.com' AND NOT (AdmUsers.id = 15)) LIMIT 1`

Comment: looks like the rules is not being fired

Comment: hey @ndm my bad... I'm doing something wrong, I'm formulation an answer to explain it better

Comment: hey @ndm now I have a new issue.. I updated the question.

Comment: Are you passing club_id in the request data?

Comment: Thanks @JoséLorenzo I wasn't. The `club_id` is stored at `$this->Auth->user('club_id')` so I'm doing `$this->request->data['club_id'] = $this->Auth->user('club_id')` in the `controller` after `if ($this->request->is('post')) ...`. Is working but is the best approach?

Comment: That is a good way, the other way is to use the associations system, pass a club entity to your user entity and let it save. If you go that way, you will need to use the `buildRules()` function instead of validation to make sure the uniqueness is checked.